# Convert outputstream byte array into string

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to send a file path to a Rest Api through DataOutputStream. DataOutputStream converts string into bytes and I am having trouble converting the byte back to desired String.
Here is my method that calls Api

```
private void sendFilePath(String filePath) {
  try {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/uploadExcelFile");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) 
      url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www- 
      form-urlencoded");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);

     DataOutputStream outputStream = new 
       DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(filePath);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            connection.getResponseCode();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and here is controller method aka Api

```
@PostMapping("/uploadExcelFile")
    public HttpStatus uploadFile(@RequestBody byte[] byteFilePath) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            baos.write(byteFilePath);
            String filePath = baos.toString();
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(filePath));
            List<StudentModel> students = studentService.convertExcelToData(workbook);
            return studentHandler.createStudent(students);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        }
    }
```

The filepath argument in sendFilePath() is `D:\Projects\AutoFeeChallan\Aptech Student Records.xlsx`

while the one I get in uploadApi after converting to String is `D%3A%5CProjects%5CAutoFeeChallan%5CAptech+Student+Records.xlsx=`

I want the same path in controller method as I send as argument in sendFilePath().
Can you suggest any solution or other methods to solve this problem.

Comment: Do not use a DataOutputStream to convert a string to bytes. Wrap the OutputStream with a OutputStreamWriter using an explicit encoding.

Comment: You are sending the data via `HttpURLConnection`, which has URL-encoded the data, and you have somehow managed to receive it without URl-decoding. It has nothing to do with `DataOutputStream` whatsoever. NB It is rather pointless to call `getResponseCode()` without seeing what it actually is. What the point is of sending a client-side path to a server remains a mystery. Surely you should be sending the content of the file?

Comment: The other way around, create a ByteArrayInputStream and initialize it with your byte array. Then wrap it with a InputStreamReader (and the same encoding) and maybe BufferedReader.

Comment: @vanje None of those suggestions addresses the fact of URL-encoding, which is the issue here.

Comment: @user207421 I understand what you told and consider myself stupid

Comment: @user207421 I want to send StudentModel object to my controller function. How can I achieve that

Comment: This code makes no sense as a file uploader. Consider a server running in AWS in Germany. You’re a dude sipping coffee in a Starbucks in Dubai and want to upload a file. Are you going to go to Germany for that and hook up your computer with the server for it to have access to the file path?

Comment: What's a `StudentModel`? Can you use Serialization?

Answer (score 0):

By setting ,

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www- 
      form-urlencoded");
```

you made the data URL encoded.At some point you need  to urldecode it.

```
String filePath = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(baos.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Or you can change the content-type to different one.

Comment: Please explain your answer, code only answers are not helpful. Why does this code work? What is the problem with OP’s code that this code solves?

Comment: That setting doesn't do the encoding by itself AFAIK, although OTOH I can't see what does inn the OP's code.